# AttributeError -Settings' object has no attribute 'CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK'

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I am trying to buildtodo list webapp in django.
when i try to run 'python manage.py runserver' but am receiving this error
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK'
Any help on how to fix this and get my localhost running?

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK

Comment: views.py
def index(request):
    item_list = Todo.objects.order_by("-date")
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TodoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('todo')
    form = TodoForm()

    page = {
        "forms": form,
        "list": item_list,
        "title": "TODO LIST",
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', page)

Comment: Settings.py 
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'todo', 'crispy_forms', 'django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', –

Answer (score 9):

I guess you're trying to use the Django Crispy package latest release (2.0). If that's the case, you might likely encounter that challenge.
To fix it:

1. First include this in your `settings.py`

   CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
2. After doing that you might encounter a challenge that the template does not exist. If that occurs, make sure you have crispy-bootstrap installed - `pip install crispy-bootstrap4` and add 'crispy_bootstrap4' to your list of INSTALLED_APPS.